# A way to overwrite few positions in file

Tags: c++, c, configuration-files

I correctly read values from some positions in my file, but I'm getting problem when I need to rewrite those values. It all messes up in file, after what my file reader doesn't find what he needs at required positions. Is there some way to overwrite the whole line, and to avoid these situations?
I am using lseek() function to move file pointer to position I need.

Comment: For configuration (and for logging, and for time measurement) I'm happily using Sqlite3. Using a database for such tasks has great benefits and little drawbacks

Comment: The most secure way in my opinion is to do it the 'good old' way: load file into buffer, edit, and write the buffer back to the file.

Comment: Can you share the code or tell us how you are writing back to the file.

Comment: Also mention whether it is c or c++ or both, it would be greatly helpful for users to answer your query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you say "line", I assume you're talking about text files.

In that case: no, there's no way to overwrite a single line, *except* if the new line you want to write is *exactly* the same length.

This is because the file abstraction on disk doesn't work like editing a file in e.g. a text editor, you can't do insert/delete in the middle without re-writing all the trailing data after the point of the change.

In general you need to construct the change in memory and overwrite the entire file (or at least the part starting with the change).

Comment: Problem is that vary according to those values. Length goes from 19 to 21 bytes in file. Yes it is text file.

Comment: @Zola: what unwind's said is still true... if you can initially write the lines padded to length 21 (e.g. add spaces at the end), then you can ovewrite, otherwise you need to shift all the file content to make or fill space (just as for a `std::vector` or `std::string`).

Answer (score 0):

You can

1. read the tail after the line to change, and write it back together with the change, or
2. resort to memory mapped files: you do the change like you'd do with C-strings, and the OS takes care of the rest.

I'd prefer the memory mapped file. When portability is an issue, boost has a portable abstraction for them. I'd consider that before resorting to variant 1.